# How to print a value depending on user input in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

In python 2.7, I want to print the price of a place depending on the given user input of people. The price should vary each time the user input a different amount of people.

```
from Tkinter import *

top = Tk()
top.geometry("500x500")
a = Label(text="Adult:")
a.place(x=50,y=100)
adult_input = Entry(top)
adult_input.place(x=100,y=100)
adult_num = Label (text="x RM 5.00 per pax :")
adult_num.place(x=250,y=100)
top.mainloop()
```

How should I go about printing the the price depending on the user input?

Comment: use `Button` to execute function which will do what you need, or bind event with function to `Entry` (ie, `bind(<KeyRelease>', function_name)` ) so it will be executed every time you put new char in entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution for your situation. Add the following lines just before `top.mainloop()`:

```
b = Button(top,
           text="Confirm",
           command=lambda: adult_num.config(text=adult_input.get()))

b.place('''anywhere''')
```

This will update your `adult_num` label when clicking the button.

If this is not enough, and you need to compute a value before displaying it, then you'll need a function.

Suppose you have an `f` function:

```
def f(adults_number):
    adults_number = int(adults_number)
    return '''the result of some formula'''
```

Then you'll have to call it in the button's `command`:

```
b = Button(top,
           text="Confirm",
           command=lambda: adult_num.config(text=str(f(adult_input.get()))))
```

Also, your `adult_num` label should be attached to `top`, so the declaration should be:

```
adult_num = Label(top, text="...")
```

Comment: But what if i want to sum the grand total of 3 different function but at the same time remain the individual values for each of the price.
eg.
def adultfunc(adult_number):
    adult_number = int(adult_number)
    return(adult_number * 5.00)

def childfunc(child_number):
 child_number = int(child_num)
 return(child_number * 2.00)

def seniorfunc(senior_number):
 senior_number = int(senior_num)
 return(senior_number * 2.00)
How should go about my button so that it will compute 3 individual prices as well as the grand total consisting of the sum of all 3 prices? @Right leg

Comment: @Lek The big problem with your code is that it's one block with no functions. Because of this, adding more complex behaviours is a pain in the neck. Pretty much anytime you think "I want to do this", write a function. I gave you the general idea, but the rest is up to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Button` to execute function which will calculate value

```
import Tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def recalc():
    value = e.get()
    if value != '':
        l['text'] = float(value) * 5.00

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<KeyRelease>', recalc)

l = tk.Label(root)
l.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Recalc", command=recalc)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

or you can bind event to `Entry` and it will be calculated after every key.

```
import Tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def recalc(event): # bind executes function with argument `event`
    #value = e.get()
    value = event.widget.get()
    if value != '':
        l['text'] = float(value) * 5.00

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<KeyRelease>', recalc)

l = tk.Label(root)
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```